# What does the torch.gather and torch.index_select do?

Tags: python, pytorch

Basically when to use [torch.gather](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) vs [torch.index_select](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.index_select.html)

I have a scenario where I am using positional embedding (max_len, batch_size, embedding_dim). Here, I would like to select only particular indices from the max_len axis. I want the result to be (new_indices, batch_size, embedding_dim).

Searching around I found two functions but there purpose seem to be the same. Can someone exaplain which will be ideal for my situation and why? I am just curious.

Answer (score -1):

I made a post about this (because I also always kept forgetting).

The jist is in this image, the full version is [here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/advanced-selection-from-tensors-in-pytorch-f012e52eef80) if you're interested.

[image]